# React multiple css loaders in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am using react-bootstrap and css modules. In my webpack.config.js i am able to run my bootstrap.css with this config:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
```

However my css modules should have this setup:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: [
        'style?sourceMap',
    'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    ]
}
```

How do I combine them to make it work for css modules and react-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might keep both loaders: one for **global CSS** (like Bootstrap) and the other for **CSS modules**.

In order to avoid conflicts between loaders with same `test` property, use webpack's rules [include](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-include) and [exclude](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-exclude) properties:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
  include: [
    /* Paths to Bootstrap and further global CSS only */
  ]
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loaders: [
    'style?sourceMap',
    'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  ],
  include: [
    /* eg. Paths to your source directory  */
  ]
}
```